# Looking for application that simplifies for non techie people accessing unix/linux env

Tags: ssh, graphical-user-interface

I searched the net but didn't found any application that wrap ssh connection with GUI interface so that non techie
people can connect to unix/linux accounts and work with files , so it will looks like there familiar Microsoft windows directory structure .
Please don’t answer with .. just use xserver and such must of our servers don’t have any GUI installed .

Answer (score 6):

[WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) comes to mind. Or [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/). And those are only the most common.

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be an ssh connection? WinSCP would work fine there.

If not, then you could also configure SAMBA and let the users access their directories through the default home share.

Comment: no samba and yes ssh also , i need GUI wrapper on top of ssh and sftp i guess just click on it and you connected with GUI display